# Reason for separate Volume Container

Tags: docker

I've found following docker composition:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.1
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
  cron:
    image: schnitzler/mysqldump
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./bin/crontab:/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
      - ./bin/backup:/usr/local/bin/backup
    volumes_from:
      - backup
    command: ["-l", "8", "-d", "8"]
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: db
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
  backup:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
      - ./backup:/backup
```

What advantages does it bring to use a separate backup container and volume from that over volume the ./backup directory directly into the cron container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On modern Docker I'd never use this pattern, and in particular I'd avoid `volumes_from:`.

`volumes_from:` has the two problems of not being clear of what exactly it's mounting and not having any control over where it gets mounted.  If the image for your `backup` had a `VOLUME` declaration in its Dockerfile, for example, that volume would get mounted in your `cron` container at the exact same path as in the `backup` container, even though it's not listed in this `docker-compose.yml` anywhere.  That can lead to surprising outcomes.

Docker didn't always have named volumes.  Before there were named volumes, the way to get persistent sharable storage was to create a *data volume container* that created an anonymous volume, and then run other containers with `docker run --volumes-from ...` to attach that storage.  Now that named volumes exist, there's not a need to do that any more.